# Django model inheritance, filtering models

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Given the following models:(don't mind the TextFields there're just for illustration)

```
class Base(models.Model):
   field1 = models.TextField()

   class Meta:
      abstract=True

class Child1(Base):
   child1_field = models.TextField()

class Child2(Base):
   child2_field = models.TextField()


class Content(models.Model):
    aso_items = models.ManyToManyField('Base')
```

According to these definitions a Content object can be associated with more than one Base object, eg. an interview(=Content object) can be linked with a musician(=Child1 object), a filmdirector(=Child2), etc.

Now, for my question:
Is it possible to filter Content objects according to which model the aso_items field points to?
An example : Say I would like a Queryset containing all the Content objects that are associated with a specific object of Child1(eg. all the interviews associated with the musician Bob Dylan), how can I achieve this?

Further, what if I'd want a QuerySet containing all the Content objects that are associated with Child1 objects?(eg. all the interviews that associated with musicians)
How does this change the filtering?

Thanks in advance
ps: I'm experiencing some problems with white space in the preview, forgive me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check the section of the Django docs regarding using `related_name` for abstract base classes. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name

To quote the docs:

> If you are using the `related_name`
>   attribute on a ForeignKey or
>   ManyToManyField, you must always
>   specify a unique reverse name for the
>   field. This would normally cause a
>   problem in abstract base classes,
>   since the fields on this class are
>   included into each of the child
>   classes, with exactly the same values
>   for the attributes (including
>   `related_name`) each time.
>
> To work around this problem, when you
>   are using related_name in an abstract
>   base class (only), part of the name
>   should be the string `%(class)s`. This
>   is replaced by the lower-cased name of
>   the child class that the field is used
>   in. Since each class has a different
>   name, each related name will end up
>   being different.

Using this information I would recommend moving the m2m field into the Base class:

```
class Content(models.Model):
   # Add remaining fields for Content 
   pass

class Base(models.Model):
   field1 = models.TextField()
   items = models.ManyToManyField(Content,related_name="%(class)s_related")

   class Meta:
      abstract=True

class Child1(Base):
   child1_field = models.TextField()

class Child2(Base):
   child2_field = models.TextField()
```

Comment: This is a good solution if the Content model isn't abstract too. 

If the Content model were also abstract an abstract model then it would no longer work.(but this a different problem than what I posted)

Comment: Fair enough.  In the case where both are abstract I think that you would have to use the ContentType framework as Adam suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently a ForeignKey relation(or ManyToMany for that matter) with a abstract class isn't allowed.
I get the following error : 'AssertionError: ForeignKey cannot define a relation with abstract class Artiest'.

A possible solution is to define the base class as non-abstract, however this implies that one could instantiate models of the base class. Which isn't the behavior I want.(after all it was an abstract class) 
Has someone come accross the same problem how did you solve it? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/ which goes through generic relations.  Your Content model would match up to their TaggedItem model, and your Base model would match up to their Animal/Vegetable/Mineral model (with Child1 and Child2 extending).

Getting all of the Content objects for a single child would be (assuming you set the GenericRelation to contents inside Base):

```
child_contents = childObject.contents.all()
```

And to get all Content objects for a model:

```
ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Child1)
all_child_contents = Content.objects.filter(content_type=ctype)
```

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for, the ContentType framework which is enables the use of generic relations is documented at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/.


The comments app standard in django(django.contrib.comments) uses this framework, thus providing usuable sample code. I'm looking into it now.

Comment: I'm concerned about performance, our site gets about 11k hits/day and I would like my solution to be scalable offcourse.(the hitcount could rise for example) Can anyone shed some light on this matter?
The production server will run on a VPS of slicehost.