# django: querying ManyToMany attribute calling multi table inheritance

Tags: django, inheritance, orm, many-to-many, generics

I've read [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147749/django-orm-inheritance-with-manytomany-field), [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933092/generic-many-to-many-relationships), [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393622/django-model-inheritance-filtering-models), but it's not very clear what the best practice is for my case.
I'm a database n00b trying to learn, so patience is appreciated.  My situation is as follows:

- 3 types of companies: Manufacturer, Reseller, ServiceNRepair (sharing about 10 attributes)
- 5 types of products: StuffedAnimals, Bicycles, Barbies (also sharing some attributes)

So to keep things DRY I tried multi table inheritance:

```
# company.models.py

class GenericCompany(models.Model):
    name, description, address, etc

class Manufacturer(GenericCompany): #can manufacture different things
    stuff_specific_to_manufacturers
    product = models.ManyToMany(GenericProduct)

class Reseller(GenericCompany): #can sell different things
    stuff_specific_to_manufacturers
    product = models.ManyToMany(GenericProduct)

etc for ServiceNRepair
```

and similarly for the products,

```
# product.models.py

class GenericProduct(models.Model):
    name, price, color, etc

class StuffedAnimal(GenericProduct):
    fluffyness, ears_or_not, etc


class Bicycle(GenericProduct):
    wheel_diameter, weight, etc


etc for Barbies
```

Now I'm going to need to perform queries like

- Show all products that are red (this is easy)
- What products does this manufacturer produce?
- Find all bicycles that reseller X sells

But can I do so with M2M? `Manufacturer.objects.filter(product_icontains ='something')` such things won't work.  So, I'm I totally on the wrong path?  Is the typical solution to use ContentTypes?  I would just like some direction about what to study next to tackle this problem which surely must be quite common.  Any tips appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do things like `Manufacturer.objects.filter(product__name__icontains='something')`, just add a name of the field in Product.

Comment: though you don't need even that for the queries you've mentioned